# multiplying dynamically generated selectbox and textbox values and displaying the result in another textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

In the below fiddle I have written the code to multiply textbox(qty,price) and selectbox(Tax%) values and fill the Total textbox value with the result of caluculate(javascript function).

Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fvJgE/13/ for the code.Can anybody spot What I'm missing or where I'm doing wrong?

Jquery Code

```
var count = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if(count>7){
                alert("Only 7 textboxes allow");
                return false;
                }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + count);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          '<label>Desc #'+ count + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="4" name="desc[]" id="desc' + count + '" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
          <label>Tax #'+ count + ' : </label>' +
      '<select id="tax_type' + count + '" ><option value="tax1">VAT</option><option value="tax2">ST</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
          <label>Tax% #'+ count + ' : </label>' +
          '<select id="tax_per' + count + '" ><option value="Vat">5.5</option><option value="ST">14.5</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
          <label>Qty #'+ count + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="1" name="qty[]" id="qty' + count + '" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
          <label>price #'+ count + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="2" name="price[]" id="price' + count + '" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
      <label>Total #'+ count + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" size="3" name="total[]" id="total' + count + '" value="" >'
    );

          newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
            $('#qty' + count).on("blur", function() {
            calculate($(this));
           });
            $('#price' + count).on("blur", function() {
            calculate($(this)); 
            });
            $('#tax_per' + count).on("change", function() {
            calculate($(this)); 
            });

           count++;  

        });//closing the addButton function     

        //To caluculate Total amount based on price and tax percentage   
         function calculate(el) {
        var count = el.attr("id").indexOf("qty") != -1 ?               el.attr("id").substring(3) : el.attr("id").substring(5);
        var qty = isNaN(parseFloat($('#qty' + count).val())) ? 0 :      parseFloat($('#qty' + count).val());
        var price = isNaN(parseFloat($('#price' + count).val())) ? 0 :     parseFloat($('#price' + count).val());
        var tax_per = isNaN(parseFloat($('#tax_per' + count).val())) ? 0 :            parseFloat($('#tax_per' + count).val());
        var value = qty*price;
        //alert(value);
        var tax_amt = (value*tax_per)/100;
        //alert(tax_amt);
        var total_value = value + tax_amt;
        $("#total" + count).val(total_value);
        }


          //To remove the added textboxes
          $("#removeButton").click(function () {
                if(count==0){
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
                }
                count--;

                $("#TextBoxDiv" + count).remove();
                });

         });
```

HTML Code

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" class="add" >
    <input type="button" id="removeButton" value="Delete" class="remove" >
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>

        </div>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The value gets displayed in the Total textbox but its not considering the selectbox(Tax%) value in caluculation. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because the **values** in the `tax_perc` select element are actually the strings "VAT" and "ST". I think you meant to put the original values in there (5.5,14.5 respectively) so that when you call

```
$('#tax_perc'+count).val()
```

You actually read 5.5 (or 14.5) to do the multiplication.

In other words, change this:

```
'<select id="tax_per' + count + '" ><option value="Vat">5.5</option><option value="ST">14.5</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
```

For:

```
'<select id="tax_per' + count + '" ><option value="5.5">5.5</option><option value="14.5">14.5</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
```